# How an application install and register in run of registery to run automatically with non Administrator user

Tags: c#, registry

I have an application that register himself to run of windows registry by this:

```
RegistryKey rk1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
       "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
var value1 = rk1.GetValue(KeyName);
if(value1 == null)
    rk1.SetValue(KeyName, KeyValue);


RegistryKey rk2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
       "Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
var value2 = rk2.GetValue(KeyName);
if(value2 == null)
    rk2.SetValue(KeyName, KeyValue);
```

I install the application with Administrator user and I want automatically run it in every log in with all users, but with this implementation the application don't run in limited users log in, so what is your suggestion?

**Edit:**

with administrator user all things worked perfectly but with limited user the application never started.

Comment: Does you app run when you login as Administrator? When you login as limited user, does the application start and terminates because it cannot do the job or it simply does not start?

Comment: @Macro I answered by new update the question

Comment: How can you tell the app never started? Did you log its "start" writing to a file in a system location accessible to everyone? Which OS?

Comment: @Marco No I am not logged any start, and I try it in win xp

Comment: OK, so first thing you should do is write to a file some message (it's called logging) to understand why your app does not work. If you write to log "App started" at the very beginning, you can understand if it runs (so check later messages to understand where it stops) or not

Comment: @Marco OK, what do you think about logging whit this: `string DefaultFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "log.txt");    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(DefaultFilePath , true)) {
     sw.WriteLine(Message);
     sw.Flush();
    }`

Comment: No, directory in which your sw stays could not be writable to users. Try this: `string fname = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),"your_app_name", "log.txt"); File.AppendAllText(fname, "Started");`
`

Comment: @Marco Thank you, All of the problems was about to access to the GetExecutingAssembly() location. and now working perfectly.

Comment: Can I post my comment as answer so you can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should do is to write to a file some message (it's called logging) to understand why your app does not work.
If you write to log "App started" at the very beginning, you can understand if it runs (so check later messages to understand where it stops) or not.
Don't use (as in your comment) directory in which your exe stays to log, because it could not be writable to limited users.
Try this:

```
string fname = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicatio‌​nData),
    "your_app_name", "log.txt"); 
File.AppendAllText(fname, "Started");
```